# Change color of shape in Layer File

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I currently have a layer file - in this case one of the United States.  This layer contains a shape for each state so if I were to open the TOC Control and expand the "United States"  I would see Alabama, Alaska, etc etc.

Currently, if I wanted to I could change the color of all the states through the following code:

```
IRgbColor rgb = new RgbColorClass();
ColorDialog myColorDlg = new ColorDialog(); ///This is the windows color picker

DialogResult res = myColorDlg.ShowDialog();

if(res == DialogResult.OK)
{
   IFeatureLayer featureLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
   IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

  rgb.Red = myColorDlg.Red;
  rgb.Blue = myColorDlg.Blue;
  rgb.Green = myColorDlg.Green;

  IGeoFeatureLayer geoFeatureLayer = layer as IGeoFeatureLayer;

  ILineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
  lineSymbol.Width = 1.0;
  lineSymbol.Color = (IColor)rgb;

  ISimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
  fillSymbol.Outline = lineSymbol;
  fillSymbol.Color = (IColor)rgb;

  ISimpleRenderer simpleRenderer = new SimpleRendererClass();
  simpleRenderer.Symbol = (ISymbol)fillSymbol;
  geoFeatureRenderer.Renderer =  (IFeatureRenderer)simpleRenderer;

  myAxMapControl.Refresh();
}
```

The question now is, how can I change each state separately.  I'm aware that if I use the built in TOC control I should be able to do this with ILegendClass; however, I wish to use a different TOC Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IUniqueValueRenderer.Field Property**
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000rs0000000

Comment: That webpage also links to sample code.